# can I inject @transactional properties into annotation?

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-annotations, spring-el

I have services that are defined in a Spring context file and we are injecting the transactional properties using EL:

```
...
<bean id="basicStarTrans" class="java.lang.String">
   <constructor-arg value="PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly" />
</bean>
...
<property name="transactionAttributes">
   <props>
      <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
      <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
      <prop key="*"><b>#{basicStarTrans}</b></prop>
   </props>
</property>
```

I have a few services that are defined using the `@Service` annotation.  Is it possible to inject a property similar to the way we do it in the xml file and what would the syntax be? i.e:

```
@Transactional("#{transactionalSettings}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a deeper look at the `<tx:>` namespace.  I think it'll have what you need:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html